# Using if/else with twig based on viewport size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, responsive-design, twig

I'm using twig to create a small responsive website to list out photos from an array over several pages.  For the front-end, I'm using bootstrap to list to display them in neat rows for each device.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
   {% for index, photo in photos %}
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
      {% if (index + 1) % 2 == 0 %}
         </div>
           <div class="row-fluid">
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}     
   </div>
 </div>
```

I want this to list out and start a new row if there's 2 on mobile, or 3 in a row on a larger device.  My question is based on this line;

```
  {% if (index + 1) % 2 == 0 %}
```

Based on the screen size, I'd like to be able to change the `2` to be a higher value if the viewport is a certain width to display more products in a row.  I can't think of a solution for doing this.  I know I could use Ajax to pass the width of the viewport when the screen resizes, but I'm not show how I could set that value to automatically update my twig if statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible with `twig`. As `twig` is "compiled" to `PHP` and `PHP` is interpretted serverside, you will need to use mediaqueries to change the amount of items per row

Comment: You have to use block grid like Zurb Foundation has, there is one for Bootstrap: https://github.com/JohnnyTheTank/bootstrap-block-grid

Comment: @DarkBee it's technically possible if you detect user agent for mobiles, or set cookie in JavaScript.

Comment: @malcolm that would defeat the purpose, I agree you could do this, but then you should check this in the controller and use different templates e.g. `grid_row_2.twig` and `grid_row_3.twig` instead of hacking it into `twig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that twig has [special loop variables](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) that you 'might' be able to use. However, I'm not certain if it will work. Can you try it out:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    {% for photo in photos %}
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
        {% if (loop.index + 1) % 2 == 0 %}
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}     
        </div>
</div>
```

No guarantee that it will work though - but try it!

Comment: Thanks @Alvin, I didn't know about that feature before.  It won't solve the issue I'm having now but it will help out in other areas

Comment: @Sawyer05 offtopic, `{% if loop.index0 is even %}`, is a bit nicer to do the check

Comment: Hi Sawyer05. Glad to help out. What other issue are you having? If you think this answered the original question, you can mark it as the correct one, since other people might search for a similar question. Also, post another question if the 'issue you are having now' is different. @DarkBee suggestion in the comment is a good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks both @DarkBee and Alvin. Managed to get this working with your suggested code.

Comment: @Sawyer05 can you share your solution how you make mobile layout with twig based on suggested code? I mean 2 columns on mobile and 3 for large devices that you asked in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In pure Twig, no, not really possible as @DarkBee explained in the comment section. But, it is fairly easy if you would combine `Twig` AND `CSS`, with some bogus elements printed in `Twig`:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    {% for photo in photos %}
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
            <!-- YOUR PHOTO GOES HERE -->
        </div>
        {% if (loop.index + 1) % 2 == 0 %}
            <div class="visible-xs"></div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}     
        </div>
</div>
```

And by looking up the `visible-xs` ([official docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)), that is nothing more than:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /* ... */
    .visible-xs {
        display: block !important;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

So, I guess, you could create your own class similar to this and tweak it to your needs.

Hope this helps.